How can I print countdown from 255 to 0 in assembly language in emu 8086?
It's my first time using assembly. This code functions correctly, but it outputs ASCII characters instead of the actual numbers.
; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
    ; add your data here!
    pkey db "press any key...$"
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    
    ; add your code here!

    mov ax, 255  ; Initialize AX with 255 (FFh)
loop_start:
    ; Output value in AX
   
    mov dx, ax  ; Move value in AX to DX for printing
    mov ah, 2h  ; AH=2 is the DOS function for displaying a character
    int 21h     ; Call DOS interrupt to print character in DL (which is now AX)

    dec ax      ; Decrement AX (decrease countdown value)

    cmp ax, 0   ; Compare AX with 0
    jnz loop_start  ; Jump back to loop_start if AX is not zero
                 
                 
                 
            
    lea dx, pkey
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h        ; output string at ds:dx
    
    ; wait for any key....    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    
    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.


I searched for alternative interrupts and other methods, but the screen displays strange characters like '# # #'.

Since you are printing characters. You will need to convert your number to characters (strings). Note that for example 123 will require 3 characters. See any of the multiple questions about this topic.

As an alternate solution you could of course count down in text without doing a conversion.
